linux : Cache coherency after DMA
In a linux kernel driver, before initiating DMA from device to RAM I'm calling:
DmaHandle = dma_map_single (sDevice, VirtualAddress + Offset, Size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
dma_sync_single_for_device (sDevice, DmaHandle, Size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

Upon DMA completion, I'm calling:
dma_sync_single_for_cpu (sDevice, DmaHandle, Size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE)
dma_unmap_single (sDevice, DmaHandle, Size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE)

It works.
But I also have another DMA from device to RAM.
This DMA is initiated, but we can't wait till it ends.
We poll a "Receive count" register which tells us how many bytes we got.
Let's say we got 128 bytes.
I have to read those bytes immediately and process them.
In order to do it I'm calling:
DmaHandle = dma_map_single (sDevice, VirtualAddress, ReceiveCount, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
dma_sync_single_for_device (sDevice, DmaHandle, ReceiveCount, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

dma_sync_single_for_cpu (sDevice, DmaHandle , ReceiveCount, DMA_FROM_DEVICE)
dma_unmap_single (sDevice, DmaHandle , ReceiveCount, DMA_FROM_DEVICE)

I'm doing this every time "Receive count" > 0.
VirtualAddress is incremented each time according to the "Receive count" register.
Do you think it can work?

This looks like it's a programming question better suited for Stack Overflow?
